# Develope an application for windows and Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cross-platform, juce

I need to develop an application that can be run on both Windows and Mac OS X, is a application "monitor" that needs to display data in real time, connection over ethernet. I'm interested in the performance and graphics. I know very well the c++. can you help me in choosing a development tool?thank you

Comment: are you asking about a cross-compiler, IDE, library, what?

Comment: Thanks first!
I'm looking a compiler suite that allow me to develop an application 
that can be run both of windows (where it will be implemented) and on Mac OS. I have to develope a GUI tool with some data analisys e.g. RealTime Graph, data acquisition via ethernet interface.
I have to maintain good ferformance.
I would hope to use objective c++

Comment: Xojo can create multi platform, native apps for Windows, OS X, Linux (plus web and iOS). 
Http://www.xojo.com

Comment: You can use QT. It supports windows, linux, osx, android, and some more.

Comment: I also thought the suite juce having to make a product for the music market, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

JUCE is not just about for Music industry. Its for all. I have used it in Music softwares, Image processing and only GUI applications too.
Its a well built library which supports all platform. 
you need not to create different project files for the application. JUCE creates it for you.
And its pure C++.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your two choices are Juce or Qt. Juce is geared toward audio and graphics, letting you get your hands on creating fast and powerful DSP algorithms. Although Juce's largest following is with developers making music software, it's fully capable of making general purpose applications with the same ease as Qt. Qt does have advantages resulting from it's greater adoption; you will find plenty of tutorials, books and courses on Qt but hardly much on Juce at the moment.

Hopefully that will change soon as Juce was bought out by ROLI and will likely have more resources soon.

Comment: Thanks for your interest! are still being evaluated, I'm doing it in my spare time. I noticed the lack of documentation and examples of juce respect on Qt, those are very important, even to begin to develop without losing too much time. Another thing that I want to keep in cosider is that the framework will also be used for other tools and the use of a generic framework perhaps is the winning choice. Qt seems a more general framework than juce.Any advice or comment are appreciated, it is a new world for me ...